# How can I accept one variable or multple when using a function?

Tags: python

I'm looking to create a search function similar to my rent_book fuction that allows me to search by first name, second name or title or any combination of the three. So I could maybe search for first name "George" and title "Animal Farm" or just title "Animal Farm" and receive the same result.

Books are stored in a list of dictionaries this is the dict struct and the rent_book function. I could do a convoluted nest of ifs but I'm sure there's a better way.

```
book = {
    "fname": fname,
    "sname": sname,
    "title": title,
    "avail": True
}

def rent_book(self, fname, sname, title):
    # if is_return is False:
        for x in self.lstBooks:
            if x['fname'] == fname and x['sname'] == sname and x['title'] == title and x['avail'] is True:
                x['avail'] = False
                return True
        return False
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your arguments are the same as the dictionary keys you're matching, you could just use `**kwargs` and iterate over the kwargs:

```
def rent_book(self, **kwargs):
    # if is_return:
    #    return False
    if not kwargs:
        raise KeyError("Must search on at least one of fname, sname, or title.")
    for x in self.lstBooks:
        if not (x['avail'] and all(x[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items())):
            continue
        x['avail'] = False
        return True
    return False
```

Note that the function will implicitly raise `KeyError` if it's called with any invalid keys (the `x[k]` will raise it), and there's an explicit `raise KeyError` to guard against the caller accidentally not providing any kwargs at all, since otherwise it would just return the first book in `lstBooks`.

(Yes, pedants, they can still call it with `avail=True`.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I understood Your question correctly,
But If I am correct, You want the function to work appropriately handling the following cases:

1. if all "title","fname","sname" are given.
2. if only one among the 3 is given.
3. If any pair of 2 among the 3 is given.

If that is the case You can use default Parameters in the function for all the 3.

```
def rent_book(self, fname="", sname="", title=""):
# if is_return is False:
    for x in self.lstBooks:
        if (len(fname) and x['fname'] == fname) and (len(sname) and x['sname'] == sname) and (len(title) and x['title'] == title) and x['avail'] is True:
            x['avail'] = False
            return True
    return False
```

The line

> (len(fname) and x['fname'] == fname)

makes sure that You only check the condition if fname is explicitly provided in as parameter.

So, In all the above scenarios mentioned above,
You can call the same function with only optional parameters
(Dont forget to specify the parameter name while calling else it will always consider it the value for the first parameter by default!!)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do here is think about having a Book class. Initially it needs to support sname, fname, title and avail (a flag to indicate whether or not the book is available to rent).

We could then construct a Book instance with any combination of these attributes or even none.

So let's start with this:

```
class Book:
    klist = ['sname', 'fname', 'title']
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.vars = kwargs
        for k in Book.klist:
            self.vars.setdefault(k, None)
        self.vars.setdefault('avail', True)
    @property
    def avail(self):
        return self['avail']
    @avail.setter
    def avail(self, v):
        self.vars['avail'] = v
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.vars.get(item, None)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'sname={self["sname"]} fname={self["fname"]} title={self["title"]} avail={self.avail}'
```

Defining getitem keeps the code neater and safer. The repr is optional - it just helps to see what's going on should we ever want to print an instance of this class.

Let's create a couple of Book instances and put them in a list.

```
booklist = [Book(sname='Orwell', fname='George', title='Animal Farm'), Book(sname='Fleming', fname='Ian', title='Casino Royale')]
```

Now we want to rent a book. We can provide any one or all of the main attributes. If there's a match for all of the attributes that have been passed **and** if that book is available, we'll mark it as unavailable and return True. If nothing matches or the book isn't available we return False.

```
def rent_book(**kwargs):
    for book in booklist:
        if book.avail:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if book[k] is not None and v != book[k]:
                    break
            else:
                book.avail = False
                return True
    return False
```

Now let's see what happens:

```
print(rent_book(title='Casino Royale'))
print(rent_book(title='Casino Royale'))
print(rent_book(sname='Orwell', title='Animal Farm'))
```

**Output:**

```
True # the book title matches and it's available 
False # the book title matches but it's no longer available
True # both the surname and title match so it's available
```